# Model complexity vs regularization

Tags: model-selection, regularization

How do the complexity of a model and regularization behave with each other? Like we could decrease the degree of a polynomial **or** add a regularization term. Or both?

In other words: Why is there regularization when you can simply tune down your model's complexity?

This plot is arbitrary, just wanted to add something to visualize which satisfies an example for regularization and/or for a too high model complexity.

[image: img]

Comment: Some hints about what it means to "tune down your model's complexity," as well as a description of your plot and its role in your question, might help us understand what kind of responses you are looking for.

Comment: It's a general question, not specific. I don't have a specific application/purpose in mind, just trying to understand the concept or meaning (w.r.t. to the model complexity) of regularization.

Comment: “Like we could decrease the degree of a polynomial or add a regularization term”—how is the first not a case of the second?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Good point, but only in terms of Lasso regularization, or? So why do we need it then when we can use the degree of a polynomial as a hyperparameter "on our own"?